# Crash using CGContextEndPage

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I have a strange issue creating a PDF file with Core Graphics library.

Using the **CGContextEndPage** method there's a crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) only on iOS 5.1 and above, testing on a real iPhone. This is not happening on the simulator.

What could I be doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

The PDF method has more than 300 lines. Everytime I create a new page I use CGContextBeginPage (pdfContext, &pageRect). The weird thing is that while testing on the simulator, there's no crash.

**UPDATE 2**

```
// This code block sets up our PDF Context so that we can draw to it

CGContextRef pdfContext;

CFStringRef path;

CFURLRef url;

CFMutableDictionaryRef myDictionary = NULL;

// Create a CFString from the filename we provide to this method when we call it

path = CFStringCreateWithCString (NULL, filename, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

// Create a CFURL using the CFString we just defined

url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, path, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 0);

CFRelease (path);

// This dictionary contains extra options mostly for 'signing' the PDF

myDictionary = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextTitle, title);

CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextCreator, CFSTR("MindScore"));

// Create our PDF Context with the CFURL, the CGRect we provide, and the above defined dictionary

pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL (url, &pageRect, myDictionary);

// Cleanup our mess

CFRelease(myDictionary);

CFRelease(url);

for (…) {

/** START NEW PAGE */

    if (…) {

    CGContextEndPage (pdfContext);

    }

    /** START INITIALIZATION OF PAGE*/

    if (…) {

       CGContextBeginPage (pdfContext, &pageRect); 

       // This code block will create an image that we then draw to the page

       const char *picture = "pdf-sheet";

       CGImageRef image;

       CGDataProviderRef provider;

       CFStringRef picturePath;

       CFURLRef pictureURL; 

       picturePath = CFStringCreateWithCString (NULL, picture,

        kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

       pictureURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), picturePath, CFSTR("png"), NULL);

       CFRelease(picturePath);

       provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithURL (pictureURL);

       //CFRelease (pictureURL);

       image = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider (provider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

       CGDataProviderRelease (provider);

       CGContextDrawImage (pdfContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, 2480, 3508),image);

       CGImageRelease (image);

       // End image code

    }
}

[...]

/** END LAST PAGE */

NSLog(@"END LAST PAGE");

CGContextEndPage (pdfContext);

CGContextRelease (pdfContext);
```

Comment: I just updated the description.

Comment: But you didn't show us the code that you're having problems with. We're not mind-readers.

Comment: The code is up. As I said the app crashes at the end, on the CGContextEndPage method.

Comment: You've clipped out the interesting code. You do something before ending the page that is causing the crash, but you've removed that something.